# AVAudioSession: Some Bluetooth devices are not working properly on my App

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, audio, bluetooth

I'm developing a swift audio/video and text chat iOS App using AVAudioSession.

Whenever I select to use some Bluetooth devices the sound played on the device is not the App audio stream. They play only the system sound sent by text chat library whenever messages are sent/received instead. It doesn't happen on all Bluetooth devices, on some of them everything works fine. On Builtin Mic and Speaker the App works fine too.

Here are the most important methods from my class to manage the device:

```
class MyAudioSession
{
    private var mAudioSession: AVAudioSession;

    init!()
    {
        self.mAudioSession = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance();

        do {
            try self.mAudioSession.setActive(false);

            try self.mAudioSession.setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord, withOptions: .AllowBluetooth);
            try self.mAudioSession.setMode(AVAudioSessionModeVideoChat);
            try self.mAudioSession.setActive(true);
        }
        catch {
            return nil;
        }
    }

    func switchToDevice(device: AVAudioSessionPortDescription!) -> Bool
    {
        var ret = false;

        if (device != nil) {
            do {
                try self.mAudioSession.setPreferredInput(device);

                ret = true;
            }
            catch {
                self.logSwitch(device, error: error);
            }
        }

        return ret;
    }
}
```

I'd like to understand why my App is not working fine on just SOME Bluetooth devices. These same devices work properly on the other Apps on my Cel.

I did another test: I changed all of this for MPVolumeView, and exactly the same issue occurred, so the problem seems to be on audio player.

Could anybody give me a suggestion to fix this ?

Thx.

Comment: Jorg, have you had any luck with this? We're experiencing the same issue. Some apps work with certain devices, our AVAudioSession is not. I'm logging that its an AVAudioSessionPortBluetoothA2DP but no dice on playing to it. Again, works on most BT devices but not a few select ones.

Comment: Jorg, if you are still on SO, would you mind taking a look at my recent question from 4/9/2018?  It seems similar to what you were experiencing here.  Greatly appreciated! PS - did you ever solve this?

Answer (score 4):

Jorg,
While this might not be the best answer I have been able to overcome the weird Bluetooth issues. My problem seems to be similar to yours as I too was using:

```
AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord
```

This was causing issues for me on some Bluetooth devices (not all but some).

What I wound up doing was setting the Category to:

```
AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback
```

Then when ever I needed to record I would switch the Category over to:

```
AVAudioSessionCategoryRecord
```

Then back to Playback after completing my recording.

This was the only way at this time I could get a consistent result from switching between the different outputs (Speaker, Headphones, Bluetooth).

Hope that helps some. Guessing this is a bug in the "AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord"

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I will test your solution. Unfortunately it will not solve my problem once I'm developing a videoconference App, so the device should be kept on PlayAndRecord most time. Beyond this, the Bluetooth devices that don't work properly on my App work perfecty on other Apps like WhatsApp.

Comment: No problem. Sorry I won't work out for you. If you are able to solve your issue please let me know as the solution this would be much appreciated. Thanks.