# Detect if Airpods are connected to my iPhone without using name matching?

Tags: ios, swift, avaudiosession, airpods

I am able to go through all of my available audio inputs but I need a way to identify which inputs in the bluetoothHFP category are airpods. I can't key off of "Airpods" in the name since that can be changed by the user.

```
for input in AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().availableInputs!{
    if convertFromAVAudioSessionPort(input.portType) == convertFromAVAudioSessionPort(AVAudioSession.Port.bluetoothHFP) {
        //How do I tell here that it is airpods and not another HFP device?
    }
}
```

Comment: I think what you are doing is currently infeasible. There have been questions related to this and detecting if `blutoothHFP` is the best they got. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46612223/avaudiorecorder-avaudiosession-with-apple-airpods 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54014593/how-to-check-if-airpods-are-connected-to-iphone

Comment: that is what I was afraid of and I have seen that post before. Thank you